# Same Query with MINUS and NOT IN Clause returning Different result set. Please explain why this different result sets

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Here i am having same queries one with MINUS and one with NOT IN both queries returning different result set.

Query with NOT IN Clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT ebdf.business, ebdf.data_source, ebdf.frequency,
                          c.case_symbol
                     FROM etl_mgr.etl_bus_datasrc_frequencies@etlmgr_srv_ubatchh_lx ebdf INNER JOIN etl_mgr.etl_rulesets@etlmgr_srv_ubatchh_lx er
                          ON (    ebdf.business = er.business
                              AND ebdf.data_source = er.data_source
                              AND ebdf.frequency = er.frequency
                             )
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN etl_mgr.etl_db_output_fact_rules@etlmgr_srv_ubatchh_lx r
                          ON er.ruleset_id = r.ruleset_id
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN etl_mgr.etl_db_output_fact_cases@etlmgr_srv_ubatchh_lx c
                          ON r.db_output_fact_rule_id =
                                                      c.db_output_fact_rule_id
                    WHERE (ebdf.business,
                           ebdf.data_source,
                           ebdf.frequency,
                           c.case_symbol
                          ) NOT IN (
                             SELECT c.business_unit_key, e.data_source_key,
                                    f.data_frequency_key,
                                    g.data_source_subset
                               FROM npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_module_summary_schema a INNER JOIN npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_module b
                                    ON a.module = b.module
                                    INNER JOIN npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_business_unit c
                                    ON b.business_unit_id = c.business_unit_id
                                    INNER JOIN npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_summary_source_type d
                                    ON a.summary_source_type_id =
                                                      d.summary_source_type_id
                                    INNER JOIN npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_data_source e
                                    ON d.data_source_id = e.data_source_id
                                    INNER JOIN npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_data_frequency f
                                    ON d.data_frequency_id =
                                                           f.data_frequency_id
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_data_source_subset g
                                    ON d.data_source_subset_id =
                                                       g.data_source_subset_id)
```

Same Query With MINUS Puzzled why not returning the same out put :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ebdf.business, ebdf.data_source, ebdf.frequency,
                          c.case_symbol
                     FROM etl_mgr.etl_bus_datasrc_frequencies@etlmgr_srv_ubatchh_lx ebdf INNER JOIN etl_mgr.etl_rulesets@etlmgr_srv_ubatchh_lx er
                          ON (    ebdf.business = er.business
                              AND ebdf.data_source = er.data_source
                              AND ebdf.frequency = er.frequency
                             )
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN etl_mgr.etl_db_output_fact_rules@etlmgr_srv_ubatchh_lx r
                          ON er.ruleset_id = r.ruleset_id
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN etl_mgr.etl_db_output_fact_cases@etlmgr_srv_ubatchh_lx c
                          ON r.db_output_fact_rule_id =
                                                      c.db_output_fact_rule_id
          MINUS
          SELECT c.business_unit_key, e.data_source_key, f.data_frequency_key,
                 g.data_source_subset
            FROM npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_module_summary_schema a INNER JOIN npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_module b
                 ON a.module = b.module
                 INNER JOIN npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_business_unit c
                 ON b.business_unit_id = c.business_unit_id
                 INNER JOIN npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_summary_source_type d
                 ON a.summary_source_type_id = d.summary_source_type_id
                 INNER JOIN npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_data_source e
                 ON d.data_source_id = e.data_source_id
                 INNER JOIN npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_data_frequency f
                 ON d.data_frequency_id = f.data_frequency_id
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_data_source_subset g
                 ON d.data_source_subset_id = g.data_source_subset_id
```

Comment: My guess is that it's because of NULLs.

Comment: I check for Null also but still the result set is different.

Comment: You haven't explained what difference you're seeing. More results with one that the other, different values, extra or missing rows... some clue as to the differences in the result set may make it clear why they're different. (Nulls are a good guess though).

Comment: @AlexPoole, Ok. My understanding was, if Oracle11g is mentioned, it implicitly means the DB is Oracle, so Oracle tag is not necessary. Anyway, thanks for correcting me. I would read the wiki once again.

Comment: @Pravin - why have you rolled back the formatting improvements?

Comment: I check IS NOT NULL for the selected columns in NOT IN Clause but difference is that NOT IN Clause showing  me less record as compare to MINUS Clause.

Comment: As it stands, the query is mostly irrelevant noise. Please edit the question to the smallest query possible that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`NOT NULL` is sensitive to null values, it does not compare null values hence ignores it. In contrast, `MINUS` is insensitive to null values. Check the example given below

```
SQL> create table test1 (c1 number(9), c2 varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert all
  2  into test1 values (1, 'XYZ')
  3  into test1 values (2, null)
  4  into test1 values (4, null)
  5  into test1 values (null, 'ABC')
  6  select * from dual;

4 rows created.

SQL> create table test2 (c1 number(9), c2 varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert all
  2  into test2 values (1, 'XYZ')
  3  into test2 values (2, null)
  4  into test2 values (3, 'GHI')
  5  into test2 values (null, 'ABC')
  6  into test2 values (5, null)
  7  select * from dual;

5 rows created.

SQL> select * from test2 where (c1, c2) not in (select c1, c2 from test1);

        C1 C2
---------- ----------
         3 GHI

SQL> select * from test2 minus select * from test1;

        C1 C2
---------- ----------
         3 GHI
         5

SQL>
```

Row `5, NULL` was ignored by `NOT NULL` but was considered by `MINUS`. In fact NOT NULL ignored row  `2, null` and `null, ABC`, but since they are also present in test1, it seems to be logical although ignored. This can be tested by issuing `select * from test2 where (c1, c2) in (select c1, c2 from test1);`

Comment: NOT IN clause Do i need to check for Null.

Answer (score 0):

i modified the query and able to get the right answer this time. thanks to everyone for the prompt response.

```
SELECT * FROM( SELECT DISTINCT ebdf.business || ebdf.data_source || ebdf.frequency ||c.case_symbol As D1,ebdf.business, ebdf.data_source, ebdf.frequency,
                          c.case_symbol
                     FROM etl_mgr.etl_bus_datasrc_frequencies@etlmgr_srv_ubatchh_lx ebdf INNER JOIN etl_mgr.etl_rulesets@etlmgr_srv_ubatchh_lx er
                          ON (    ebdf.business = er.business
                              AND ebdf.data_source = er.data_source
                              AND ebdf.frequency = er.frequency
                             )
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN etl_mgr.etl_db_output_fact_rules@etlmgr_srv_ubatchh_lx r
                          ON er.ruleset_id = r.ruleset_id
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN etl_mgr.etl_db_output_fact_cases@etlmgr_srv_ubatchh_lx c
                          ON r.db_output_fact_rule_id =
                                                      c.db_output_fact_rule_id) tst WHERE tst.D1 NOT IN
          (
          SELECT  c.business_unit_key || e.data_source_key || f.data_frequency_key ||  g.data_source_subset as D1

            FROM npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_module_summary_schema a INNER JOIN npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_module b
                 ON a.module = b.module
                 INNER JOIN npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_business_unit c
                 ON b.business_unit_id = c.business_unit_id
                 INNER JOIN npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_summary_source_type d
                 ON a.summary_source_type_id = d.summary_source_type_id
                 INNER JOIN npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_data_source e
                 ON d.data_source_id = e.data_source_id
                 INNER JOIN npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_data_frequency f
                 ON d.data_frequency_id = f.data_frequency_id
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN npdreportmanager_appsetup.tb_data_source_subset g
                 ON d.data_source_subset_id = g.data_source_subset_id
```